# How to export only labels as svg in QGIS 2.6?

Tags: qgis, labeling, print-composer, svg

I'm working with a big big data set in QGIS 2.6 (but also in QGIS 2.7).

I have many line layers styled with the rule rendering tool. What I want to do is to export only the labels of all these line layers as svg while the line style can be exported as png.

I tried a small work-around: I have set a total transparency for the line layer leaving only the labels. The problem is that during the svg exportation, QGIS seems to read all the line anyway and these causes an error (I suppose because the dimension of the whole file).

Is there a way to do what I need?